# An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@BPBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql

I'm receiving the error "An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@BPBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection." I can't figure out why it's fine for every other field, but this one gives an error.

```
 string[] lines7 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\BillingExport\BILLING_TABLE_FILE17.txt");


            //creating a list for segmented storage of the data in the text file 
            List<BILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION> table17Input = new List<BILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION>();

            //iterates through every line in the text file (one line at a time) , trims the data in regions appropriate to their fields , and assigns the trimmed data to list items.
            for (int i = 0; i < lines7.Length; i++)
            {
                BILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION table17 = new BILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION();
                //creates new list instance (table5)                   

                //trims the data in regions appropriate to their fields , converts the data into its proper datatype (reflecting the sql field datatype), and assigns the trimmed data to list items.
                table17.BPTABLE_NUMBER = lines7[i].Substring(0, 2).Trim();
                table17.BPCOMPANY = lines7[i].Substring(2, 2).Trim();
                table17.BPSTATE_CODE = lines7[i].Substring(4, 2).Trim();
                table17.BPBILL_CODE = lines7[i].Substring(6, 2).Trim();

                table17.BPRECORD_TYPE = lines7[i].Substring(28, 1).Trim();
                table17.BPBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION = lines7[i].Substring(31).TrimEnd();

                table17Input.Add(table17);
                //adds all table5 list instances to the list table5input 


                string datconnectionString5 = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";

                using (SqlConnection _datcon5 = new SqlConnection(datconnectionString5))
                {
                    _datcon5.Open();
                    //opens the predefined connection _con


                    string datinsertString5 = @"INSERT INTO BILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION
                    (BPTABLE_NUMBER, BPCOMPANY, BPSTATE_CODE, BPBILL_CODE, BPRECORD_TYPE, BPBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION)
                    VALUES(@BPTABLE_NUMBER, @BPCOMPANY, @BPSTATE_CODE, @BPBILL_CODE, @BPRECORD_TYPE, @BPBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION)";
                    //defines the sql insert query to be performed 

                    using (SqlCommand datcmd5 = new SqlCommand(datinsertString5, _datcon5))
                    {
                        datcmd5.Parameters.Add("@BPTABLE_NUMBER", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        datcmd5.Parameters.Add("@BPCOMPANY", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        datcmd5.Parameters.Add("@BPSTATE_CODE", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        datcmd5.Parameters.Add("@BPBILL_CODE", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        datcmd5.Parameters.Add("@BPRECORD_TYPE", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        datcmd5.Parameters.Add("@BPBBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION", SqlDbType.NVarChar);


                        datcmd5.Parameters["@BPTABLE_NUMBER"].Value = table17.BPTABLE_NUMBER;
                        //adds the list fields and their values to the sql command 

                        datcmd5.Parameters["@BPCOMPANY"].Value = table17.BPCOMPANY;

                        datcmd5.Parameters["@BPSTATE_CODE"].Value = table17.BPSTATE_CODE;

                        datcmd5.Parameters["@BPBILL_CODE"].Value = table17.BPBILL_CODE;

                        datcmd5.Parameters["@BPRECORD_TYPE"].Value = table17.BPRECORD_TYPE;

                        datcmd5.Parameters["@BPBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION"].Value = table17.BPBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION;


                        datcmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //executes to insert query

                        _datcon5.Close();
                        //closes the no longer in use database connection
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That did it. I can't believe I missed that, looked over the code so many times. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You define the parameter in the query as:

```
@BPBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION
```

You include it in the parameters as:

```
@BPBBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION
```

The names need to match exactly, they can't just be similar.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've misspelled it here:

> datcmd5.Parameters.Add("@BPBBILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

Note the extra B